# Card.io custom keyboard, manual entry screen, screen after scan

Tags: java, android, open-source, card.io

Since using [Card.io](https://www.card.io/) for credit card scanning, 
I had to face with some limitations and looking for alternative solutions.
The issues;

1- Is there any way to customize 'KEYBOARD' button on scanning screen?

2- Is there a way to start my own view after clicking on 'KEYBOARD' button?

3- Is there any way to start my own view after scanning the card for entering expiration date, cvv, card holder name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It doesn't look like the Card.io library provides any way to modify the text of that button.
2. It doesn't look like they provide any way to hook your own logic into the button either.
3. On iOS, it's possible to [use the `CardIOView` class to integrate a card scanning component into your own view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34117279/card-io-custom-manual-screen?rq=1) which would allow you to implement whatever flow you'd like... but on Android, there doesn't seem to be an equivalent to that  class.

It seems like the Card.io library is rather limited on Android, but I haven't yet been able to find any viable alternatives that support both iOS and Android.